# Laravel dynamic keys and values query writing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i want to write this query in laravel can anyone please help me please. i am new to laravel.

```
public function selectTableData($table,$condition)
{
    try{
        $query = "SELECT * from ".$table;
        if(is_array($condition))
        {
            $query .= " WHERE ";
            foreach ($condition as $key => $value) 
                $query .= $key . "= '".$value."' AND ";
            $query = rtrim($query,'AND ');
        }
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) 
            throw new Exception(mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
           return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        }
        else
            return false;
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage ());
    }       
}
```

And this aswell, i want to write this code in laravel query format

```
public function insertTableData($table,$data)
{
    try{
        // generate insert query 
        if(is_array($data)){
            $query = 'INSERT INTO '. $table.' ( ';
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) 
                $query .= $key . ',';
            $query = rtrim($query,',');
            $query .= ') VALUES (';
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) 
                $query .= '"'.$value.'",';
            $query = rtrim($query,',');
            $query .= ')';
            $result = mysql_query($query); 
            //if (!$result) {
             //   throw new Exception( 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error());
            //}
            return $result;
        }
        else
            return false;
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage ());
    }   
}
```

if it is in capsule format then it wil be good

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: this code is working perfectly for me i just need to change the query into laravel query format

Comment: Again, what have you tried and where do you get stuck? This isnt a code writing service. Ask exact questions.

Comment: these are dynamic mehtods for query in PHP pure , clear your mind, read Laravel docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this query in laravel like below.

```
$query = DB::table($table);
if(is_array($condition)) {
    foreach ($condition as $key => $value) {
        $query->where($key, "'" . $value . "'");
    }
}
$result = $query->get();
if (count($result) > 0) {
    return $result;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that your **eloquent** model class is **SomeModel**. Then You could try like the following for first query/method-

```
$query = new SomeModel();
    if(is_array($condition))
    {
        foreach ($condition as $key => $value)
            $query = $query->where($key, $value);
    }
    $result = $query->get();
```

And for the second-

```
if(is_array($data)){
        $query = new SomeModel();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) 
            $query->$key = $value;
        $query->save();        
    }
```

Hope it solves your problem :)